# bundle.js 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm trying to bundle my React app using webpack for client-side rendering and including the `bundle.js` in a  tag. However, whenever I run my app I keep getting 404 (Not Found) for the `bundle.js`. Here is my webpack.config.js:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './views/Index.jsx'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(jsx|js)$/, exclude: /node_modules/ , use: 'babel-loader' }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

`./views/Index.jsx` points to my main template file which looks like this:

**Index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from './Layout.jsx';
import Cube from './components/Cube/Cube.jsx';

class Index extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Layout title={this.props.title}>
            <Cube />
        </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default Index;
```

Where `Layout.jsx` is where I'm including the `<script src="/public/bundle.js">`:

**Layout.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>{this.props.title}</title>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/bundle.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
          {this.props.children}
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}

export default Layout;
```

Can anybody help me understand why this isn't working? This is my full project if that helps: https://github.com/MarksCode/PersonalWebsite

I think it might have to do with me using the server-side rendering [`express-react-views`](https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views) package wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are telling express to serve the public folder at all. You'll need to explicitly let express know that the public folder should serve static files, like so:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Docs here:
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Thanks Tom. I used your suggestion and bundle.js is not being used. However, when I do a `console.log()` in the `componentDidLoad()` of my Cube.jsx, nothing is getting logged out. How do I get my components to execute the whole React lifecycle?

Comment: `componentDidLoad` is not a React lifecycle event, see here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle